# emberjs - base url to show other template

Tags: javascript, ember.js

how do I make ember behave like traditional mvc.

let say my site is `mysite.com`

if I go to `mysite.com` then it loads my home template and changes the url to `mysite.com#/h`

How do I make it go to `mysite.com` and keep the url to this but use a different template  like I would a view in mvc asp.net

```
var App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function(){
    this.resource('home', {path: '/h'} );
    this.resource('about', {path: '/a'} );
    this.resource('contact', {path: '/c'} );
});

App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
     redirect: function() {
            this.transitionTo('home'); 
    }
});
```

Comment: You will need to set the location as history to get rid of the hashes. http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/specifying-the-location-api/

Answer (score 0):

Define your main template in application.hbs for instance the top and footer and between each put `{{outlet}}` and create index.hbs (put here your home content) when user make click in home route the will show home content if your want add more template on that put inside index.hbs put

{{partial "foo"}} will render the template within templates/foo.hbs and also you can use {{view "foo"}} will render the view within views/foo.js  or more {{render "foo" "bar"}} will render the view within views/foo.js using the controller within controllers/bar.js

For your route url you can use

```
App.Router.reopen({location: 'none'});
```

You can see more info in http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/specifying-the-location-api/